# CSV list (row, column) to Python list of Variables (name, value)

Tags: python, variables, csv, variable-assignment

How can I convert a CSV file of names with 3 pieces of data (in adjacent columns) into variables of a created class that takes the adjacent pieces of data as arguments?

The code below appears to create the objects but the list is of object locations and not the names as I would prefer.

Can anyone help?

```
class Teams(object):
  def __init__(self, TeamName, FT, FG, Three):
    self.TeamName = TeamName
    self.FT = FT
    self.FG = FG
    self.Three = Three

North_Carolina = Teams("North Carolina", .643,.458,.371)

print North_Carolina.TeamName, North_Carolina.FT, North_Carolina.FG,North_Carolina.Three
## works fine but manually typed data

def getData(fname):  ##fname is a csv file with 4 columns and 348 rows. One header row.
    Data = open(fname, 'r')
    TeamList = []
    #print Data.read() ## prints a list with comma separated values and line return
    for line in Data:
      info = line.split(",") ##info is a list of lists of Data with Team,FT,FG,3P
      name = info[0]
      FT = info[1]
      FG = info[2]
      Three = info[3]
      newTeam = (name, FT, FG, Three)
      newTeam2 = Teams(newTeam[0],newTeam[1],newTeam[2],newTeam[3]) ##newTeam2 is an object. 
      TeamList.append(newTeam2)
    print TeamList[1].TeamName ##prints North Carolina list[0] print header
    print TeamList #prints list of object locations but not objects themselves

getData("Stats 01-04-2013.csv")
```

First `print` statement prints:

```
North Carolina
```

Second `print` statement prints:

```
[<__main__.Teams object at 0x02953230>, <__main__.Teams object at 0x029532B0>, etc etc
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the python csv module ?

Comment: @HaraldScheirich: In this case, it's not absolutely required, since it's a fairly simple CSV. But yeah, better use the library.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you want `print Teamlist` to print. Do you want a comma-separated list of all of the team names, or a newline-separated list of (a comma-separated list of all of the team properties) for each team, or …? If I've guessed wrong in my answer, please clarify exactly what your expected output is.

Comment: The Teamlist print statement is just to check my work. I want these names (variables of team class) to be called later in the program and each piece of data is used in calculations.

Comment: For example, there is a later function simGame(teamA, Teamb) that takes the shooting percentages FT, FG and Three  of the given team and chooses whether the team makes or misses the shot based on the given percentage. Like a coin flip but weighted

Comment: You already _have_ instances of the `Teams` class. That's what it looks like when you print them out. They're really there, and correct. So… is there an actual problem here? Do you want to change what happens when you print a `Teams` or a `list` of `Teams`? Or do you want to know how to do debugging with the class as it is? Or something different?

Comment: @abarnert: I think s/he just wants the repr to print nicely as teamname instead of memory location.

Comment: I see the instances, however I am not sure how to call them in the second function. I had planned on calling them by name. In the example I gave, North_carolina can be passed to the later (not shown function) and calculations can be run on the data

Comment: @user1950044: Do you want to pass the string `"North_carolina"` to the later function, or a variable named `North_carolina` that holds a `Teams`, or do you just want some way to be able to access whichever `Teams` is named `"North_carolina"`?

Comment: The reason for the class and not hard coding of the data is that the CSV file is scraping actual team percentages. I figured with this intermediary step, I could run a simulation on any given day with that days data. More information  on the scope or context of the program.

Comment: I want to pass the variable as it stores the abstract data type (three shooting percentages) created by Teams

Comment: @user1950044: See my updated answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object locations *are* how the objects are printed out. Strictly speaking, calling `str` or `repr` on a `list` calls `repr` on each element on the list. By default, `repr(team)` on a `Teams` object will return something like `<main.Teams object at 0x02953230>`. You can override that by defining a `__repr__` method on the `Teams` class. However, this doesn't sound like what you want here.

If `TeamList` is a list of `Teams` objects, and you want to turn it into a list of their `TeamName` members, you just use a `list comprehension` to convert it:

```
TeamNameList = [team.TeamName for team in TeamList]
```

Note that this still isn't going to be exactly you want to print out:

```
>>> print TeamNameList
['North Carolina', 'South Carolina', 'West Carolina', 'East Carolina', 'Underground Carolina', 'Cloud-level Carolina', 'Past Carolina', 'Future Carolina'] # those are all states, right?
```

You probably want something like this:

```
>>> print ', '.join(TeamNameList)
North Carolina, South Carolina, West Carolina, East Carolina, Underground Carolina, Cloud-level Carolina, Past Carolina, Future Carolina
```

From your comments:

> there is a later function simGame(teamA, Teamb)
>
> I see the instances, however I am not sure how to call them in the second function. I had planned on calling them by name. In the example I gave, North_carolina can be passed to the later (not shown function) and calculations can be run on the data

I think I understand what you want here. You want to be able to simulate a game between North Carolina and South Carolina, when all you have is the `TeamList`.

To do that, you probably want to create a `dict`, mapping the names to the `Teams` objects, like this:

```
TeamDict = {team.TeamName: team for team in TeamList}
```

Now, you can do things like this:

```
simGame(TeamDict['North Carolina'], TeamDict['South Carolina'])
```

Now, `simGame` is going to get the North Carolina and South Carolina instances of the `Teams` class as its `teamA` and `teamB` arguments, so it can do things like:

```
def simGame(teamA, teamB):
    scoreA = int(teamA.FT * 1 * 20) + int(teamA.FG * 2 * 40) + int(teamA.Three * 3 * 10)
    scoreB = int(teamB.FT * 1 * 20) + int(teamB.FG * 2 * 40) + int(teamB.Three * 3 * 10)
    if scoreA > scoreB:
        print 'Home team {} beats visitor {} by {}!'.format(teamA.TeamName,
                                                            teamB.TeamName,
                                                            scoreA - scoreB)
    else:
        print 'Visitors {} win by {} over {} at home!'.format(teamB.TeamName,
                                                              scoreB - scoreA,
                                                              teamA.TeamName)
```

Is that what you want?

Some additional comments:

You can also do the same thing as the list comprehension using `map`, which avoids having to write `team` twice, but it also means you can't use normal expression syntax:

```
TeamNameList = map(operator.attrgetter('TeamName'), TeamList)
```

Or you can use `map` together with `lambda` to get back the expression syntax back… and the repeat of `team`:

```
TeamNameList = map(lambda team: team.teamName, TeamList)
```

But for cases like this, the list comprehension is generally considered the pythonic way to do it. (Also, it doesn't change if you go to Python 3, whereas `map` changes from a `list` to an iterator, which means `print TeamNameList` will give you something like `<builtins.map at 0x108022350>`… But `', '.join(TeamNameList)` will still work.)

As a side note, in standard (PEP 8) Python style, usually only classes are in TitleCase like this, and variables and attributes are in lower_case. If you really like CamelCase, you can get away with lowerFirstCamelCase, but using TitleCase will throw off people reading your code, who will immediately try to figure out where the `TeamName` class is defined. Also see the comments from bvukelic.

As another side note, you seem to be doing a lot of repeated code, and I'm not sure why:

```
  name = info[0]
  FT = info[1]
  FG = info[2]
  Three = info[3]
  newTeam = (name, FT, FG, Three)
```

You're just copying `info` to `newTeam`; why add all those intermediate variables that never get used again?

```
  newTeam2 = Teams(newTeam[0],newTeam[1],newTeam[2],newTeam[3])
```

You could replace all of that with just:

```
  newTeam2 = Teams(info[0],info[1],newTeam[2],newTeam[3])
```

Or even:

```
  newTeam2 = Teams(*info)
```

If you have a need for the separate variables somewhere that you haven't shown us, that's fine, but you still can't possibly need `newTeam`; just do this:

```
  newTeam2 = Teams(name, FT, FG, Three)
```

Comment: Speaking of PEP8 (and also according to common agreement in different languages out there), app-caps names should also not be used for anything else than constants.

Comment: @bvukelic: Good point. With two-letter abbreviated names (which themselves should be used sparingly, of course…), it doesn't seem *too* unreasonable to treat `FT` as abbreviated CamelCase instead of as ALL_CAPS… But yeah, I still wouldn't ever name anything `FT`, even if I could find a way to rationalize it away.

Comment: @abarnet: Wouldn't even do that with classes. :) I would always expand if it's too short. Also, using slightly longer names can yield self-documenting code, which is a nice thing.

Comment: This is really good stuff. The reason for these "problems" you've identified is that I'm a novice - self trained programmer so I am learning proper techniques as I go. Thanks for the help. Still reading your previous comments.

Comment: Oh and I'm new to reading code so I space things out. It's repetitive to a veteran programmer but it's the only way I prevent myself from creating syntax errors.

Comment: I think the dict concept is what I want. However, the only dictionaries I have seen map one key to one value. Are you saying I can map one key (team name) to 3 values stores as the object team?

Comment: @user1950044: There's nothing wrong with problems in your code when you're a novice. I've been using Python since version 1.5, and there are still plenty of problems in my code. Code reviews would be no fun otherwise. :)

Comment: @user1950044: No, you can only map one key to one value—but that value can itself be a `tuple` or `list` of 3 values, or an instance of a class with 3 attributes, or even another `dict`. Anything you can put in a variable, you can use as a value in a `dict`. (This is actually the same trick used to return 2 values from a function. You can't return 2 values, but you can return 1 tuple with two members, and this is almost always good enough.)

Comment: ok, then yes that is what I want. So should I open a new question on how to make a csv list into a dictionary with class values and name keys?

Comment: @user1950044: Yeah, if my example above (`TeamDict = {team.TeamName: team for team in TeamList}`) isn't enough to get you what you want, it's probably time to open another question explaining what specifically you need help with. These comments are getting a bit out of hand…

Comment: Thank you! I re-read your comments and things are clicking. Much thanks to you for your patience

Comment: @abarnert when I got to call the TeamDict["North Carolina"], I get NameError: name 'TeamDict' is not defined Any guesses why?

Comment: @user1950044: Try printing out `TeamDict` (or `TeamDict.keys()`) to see what's actually there. It'll make it easier to tell what's gone wrong.

Comment: @user1950044: One last guess before I leave for the weekend: I notice you're reading the data with `split(',')`, and not calling `strip()`. Any chance you've actually got `" North Carolina"` or `"North Carolina "` or something similar? (This, by the way, is another good reason to use the `csv` module—they already thought about all this stuff and took care of it, whereas you or I will forget about it until it bites us and then have to debug the problem…)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the csv module to do something like this, largely based on the examples in the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv). Tweaks may be needed, this is just off the top of my head, but I always use the relevant when working with these types of files.

```
import csv

with open('teams.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    teamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in teamreader:
        newTeam = Teams(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
        teamList.append(newTeam)
```

Comment: Interesting! I think I will take this idea and combine it with the Dict idea and see if I can get some elegant looking code.

Comment: +1. Not a direct answer to the OP's problem, but it will probably help make his code more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover another interpretation of the question:

```
class Teams(object):
    def __init__(self, TeamName, FT, FG, Three):
        self.TeamName = TeamName
        self.FT = FT
        self.FG = FG
        self.Three = Three

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.TeamName)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__unicode__()
```

Whenever you print the object, it will be shown as `TeamName`

Comment: True, but when you print a `list` of the objects, as the OP does, this won't help—as I explained in my answer, `str` or `repr` on a `list` calls `repr` on the elements, not `str`. And the same goes for `unicode`, of course—but with the additional problem that even `print team` won't call `unicode` on it; it calls `str`. So this will only have an effect if you explicitly do `unicode(team)` somewhere.

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, you're returning a `str` from `__unicode__`, which is quite misleading.

Comment: You've only corrected the `list` problem. There's still not `__str__`. And `__unicode__` still returns a `str` object, not a `unicode`.

Comment: OK, now it works… but why would you do `'%s' % self.TeamName` instead of just `str(self.TeamName)`?

Comment: @abarnert I don't know. Force of habit? Is there a significant difference?

Comment: Mainly that it's a bit less clear, and `str(x)` is the idiomatic OWTDI. (It's probably also a bit less efficient, but not enough that anyone sensible would ever care.) By the way, I used to do something similar to your Django deformation in my early-adopter attempts to write 2.x/3.x multi-version code, adding `__bytes__` and `__unicode__` to every class and trying to make `__str__` do the right thing in every case, and… wow, was that painful. I eventually retrained myself to do what's needed for the particular app/lib instead of trying to always be totally general.

Comment: @abarnert I appreciate your advice. I will try to keep stuff simple in future.

Comment: Here is the rest of the Sim Code  ##def gameTrial2(Team1, Team2):
  home, away = 0,0
  Team1FTMade= [1]*int((Team1[0]*1000))
  Team1FTMiss= [0]*int(((1-Team1[0])*1000))
  Team1FT = Team1FTMiss + Team1FTMade
  
  Team1FGMade= [2]*int((Team1[1]*1000))
  Team1FGMiss= [0]*int(((1-Team1[1])*1000))

Comment: elif i == 2:
      home = random.choice(Team1FG) + home
      away = random.choice(Team2FG) + away
    else:
      home = random.choice(Team13P) + home
      away = random.choice(Team23P) + away
  return home, away
  print home,away

Comment: @user1950044 You can use sites like http://pastebin.com/ to paste your code. It's much more readable that way.

Comment: ok let me try<iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=E0nu1Y3E" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

How class instances get displayed is controlled by giving them custom [`__str__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__str__) and/or [`__repr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) conversion methods. Here's one way your code could be written to do that and also make it follow many of the recommendations in the [PEP 8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You may also be able improve or simplify it even more by using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read the file, as already suggested by others, but I'll focus mostly on the code shown in your question.

```
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self, team_name, free_throws, field_goals, three_pointers):
        self.team_name = team_name
        self.free_throws = free_throws
        self.field_goals = field_goals
        self.three_pointers = three_pointers

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r}, {}, {}, {})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                                             self.team_name, self.free_throws,
                                             self.field_goals, self.three_pointers)

def get_data(fname):  # fname is a csv file with 4 columns and one header row
    teams = []
    with open(fname, 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_file.next()  # skip header row
        for line in csv_file:
            info = line.strip().split(",")
            teams.append(Team(*info))  # create a Team instance and add it to list
    return teams

print get_data("Stats 01-04-2013.csv")
```

Sample output:

```
[Team('North Carolina',  .643,  .458,  .371), Team('Michigan',  .543,  .358,  .271)]
```